# Using Transposed convolution for upsampling in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a 4D tensor of `(2,1024,4,6)`. I want to use transposed convolution for upsampling spatial dimensions of such tensor by factor of two and reducing the channel numbers from 1024 to the 512. I want to have a 4D tensor like this `(2,512,8,12)`. How can I do that? Also, is the transposed convolution a good idea for reducing the channel numbers? For example I used the following script but it is not working:

```
nn.ConvTranspose3d(in_channels=1024, out_channels=512, kernel_size=(1,2,2), stride=(1,3,2), padding=(0,1,1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you should be using [`ConvTranspose2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d.html) instead of [`ConvTranspose3d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ConvTranspose3d.html) since your input tensor is 4D, shaped `NCHW`.
There are different ways of getting to these results but one straightforward approach is to use a kernel size of `2` with a matching stride:

```
>>> conv = nn.ConvTranspose2d(1024, 512, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
```

Here is an inference example:

```
>>> conv(torch.rand(2, 1024, 4, 6)).shape
torch.Size([2, 512, 8, 12])
```